# ContentInset automatically changed after popViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform, parse-server

I have a 2 viewController

- itemViewController
- chatViewController

I had tapped right barButton to show the chatViewController

After that

I had tapped backButton to return to the itemViewController

It works fine....except of the one problem.

When I back to the itemViewController...then It automatically changed tableView's contentInset

**itemViewController snippet code is here**

in viewDidLoad function

```
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 450

        tableView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(22, 0, 0, 0)
```

I had set contentInset because My app has custom navigation bar Height which is bigger then default navigation bar height.

[image]

```
func chat(_ sender: UITabBarItem){

        var chattingObjId = String()


    //STEP 1. is Created Chatting Room?
    PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "getChattingObjId", withParameters:
        ["postId":results.objectId, "from":PFUser.current()?.username!], block: { (response: Any?, error:Error?) in

            // some your code
            if error == nil {

                chattingObjId = response as! String
                print("\(chattingObjId) : Received from Server")

                let chatting = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChattingVC") as! ChattingVC

                chatting.chattingObjId = chattingObjId


                self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chatting, animated: true)


            }else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
            }


    })

}
```

**chatViewController's snippet code below**

```
func back(_ sender: UITabBarItem){

    //push back
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)



}
```

[image]

After tapped back button then ....

[image]

There is gaps... It seems to be... 22pt which is I had set viewDidLoad..

Why It is happened?

[image]

Here is my settings of itemViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I had almost same problem, it was solved by unchecking "Adjust Scroll View Insets". Try it, maybe it will work for you too.